# What layer of the OSI model do people normally think of javascript working on?

Tags: networking, javascript

I know how the OSI model works essentially (and that they're slightly different), but I was wondering what layer of the OSI model people normally think of javascript running on.

Comment: JavaScript has nothing to do with networking, and therefore nothing to do with the OSI model.

Comment: it does when it comes to applications, like the application layer has to do with presentation of the website to the end user, presentation is code view, and session has the cookies in it. see: http://routergeeks.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/07/OSI-TCP-Model-v1.png also: http://www.tcpipguide.com/free/t_ApplicationLayerLayer7.htm

Comment: HTTP session is not L5 session, and UFT-8 vs ASCII is not L6. No modern OS that I am aware of fully complies with the OSI above layer 4. all of them leave the functionality that should be in L5/6 to the application tier. hence `<meta charset="UTF-8">` is present in millions of individual webpages, and you can kill your HTTP session by clearing your cookies, without interfering with the existing TCP connection you are engaged in.

Comment: The [OSI model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OSI_model) is modeling a communications system.  Just like the programming language C is not part of the OSI model, even though the most common network stack implementations are written in C, the programming language JavaScript is not part of the model.  You can use any programming language to access the networking stack, which is modeled by OSI, but that does not make it part of the model.  You can send JavaScript code through one of the layers (usually Layer 7 via HTTP), but that does not make it part of the model.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, your question is not as easily dismissed as HeavyD makes it out to be, but (s)he is 90% correct.

There is a Berkley Sockets implementation for js called [Socket.IO](http://socket.io/), which has calls that map to layers 7, 4, and 3. See my answer here for a discussion of how Sockets calls map to OSI layers: [What are the detailed OSI model steps involved in connecting to a website?](https://superuser.com/questions/984182/what-are-the-detailed-osi-model-steps-involved-in-connecting-to-a-website/984205#984205)

So, that said, javascript, like any programming language does not run at any particular layer. There are features and library implementations that do map to the OSI however.

OSI is about Function and responsibility, not Form, so no programming language can be said to occur at any point in the stack (including L7); its all about what you do with that language, and how it integrates with a networking stack. 99% of any code you write in any language will always be at the application tier. Accessing the network is often a trivial thing, that requires a small amount of reusable code, but what you do with the data you transfer is the real meat of any given program. For example, an AJAX refresh will call the server and ask for JSON text. The JSON and the AJAX are important, and occur at the Application layer. The actual connection to retrieve it however is almost negligible by comparison.

Comment: Can you explain the layers in the osi model as javascript is handled at that layer a little more in depth?

Comment: did you read the linked thread? it goes about as deep as I am interested in taking this, unless you have something more specific in mind. Networking is Generic; thats the point of the OSI; to make network access a commodity, not a specialty item.

Comment: example: I believe it's like at layer 7 javascript is making the client manipulate in their browser at 4 is where node.js is existing, 3 is if you're running some javascript on the router

Comment: this question will be leading up to another question for a presentation i'm writing.

Comment: If OSI was an ocean: we might describe it abstractly as a Deep Layer; a Middle Layer; and a Ship Layer. The Ship layer is the interface that the Ships touch. It is not composed of ships. As I understand the assumption behind the question, Javascript--as a linked component of a webpage--is a ship, not the ocean

Comment: First, OSI is about OS stack. It is a template for how an OS could implement a stack. It is expected that all applications and their programming languages use the OS stack to do stuff. Second, remember, OSI is about Function, not Form, so yes, you could write javascript code for a router that performed Functions that map to OSI layers 3 and 4, but that doesn't mean that javascript "is" layer 3. Languages don't map to a layer, **Functions** do. a single language will often represent an entire OSI stack, or none at all, while still being the same language.