# Does ICMP use any processes from above layer 3?

Tags: linux, networking, icmp

I'm doing a project and have to describe the process of a ping from layer 7 to 1. Ping uses ICMP which is layer 3, so the data sits at under a layer 3 header. Does this mean any layers above that just don't matter, or are they still used somehow?

Comment: Just to expand your question - assume that everything above "just don't matter" .. how does the ICMP packet travel? And after it travels, and then returned - does it just magically appears / displayed on screen? Or you need some application that understand how to send / receive / show the result to your screen? I think you'll find that you will still need some of the layers above it :)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It uses the Application Layer (7 or 4 depending on your model), and 3 and below.
ICMP is not as flexible a protocol as TCP or UDP, so it provides a rather limited set of feature. [ICMP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Control_Message_Protocol#Control_messages) supports up to [255 Command Message types](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Control_Message_Protocol#Control_messages), and does so internally, rather than using a an upper layer protocol to distribute network IO to processes.

So the Application drives the use of Command Messages to control the network. for instance Ping is an application that creates a data structure suitable for an ICMP packet, and submits it to the OS to send to an IP. it then waits for IO to return. when the IP stack receives the echo response, it passes that IO on to the program, which can then print messages to the user.

Just like TCP/IP, the application layer controls and coordinates all the primitive operations provided by the network stack, to construct capabilities of value to modern users.

if you are a code minded fellow, consider [this code snippet](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9174392) over on SO. it will listen for an ICMP message, and print it on the program output. you can see it establishes a "raw socket" for ICMP, binds that socket to an IP Interface (both layer 3 operations), establishes some data structures and reads from the socket IO, looking for a response. when an ICMP message is recieved, its data region will appear in the programs IO stream, and will be printed on the screen. Its pretty neat.

Edit as requested:

So the OSI model is an abstract representation of a way to think about responsibilities such that tasks have prerequisites (the characteristics of the protocols used in the layers below them) and post-conditions they must meet. The other thing the model does, is establish means for piping the data through each of these tasks.

The primary goal of the OSI model is to provide a description of a means for applications to easily send and receive network messages, in a way that is abstracted away from the system's configuration, making it portable across systems. In the early days, applications had to be rewritten to work other platforms and configurations, because the application had to do everything itself. by separating the responsibilities, the program can just focus on its job, and that won't vary much between systems. Additionally, the system and network administrators can change the way the system connects to other systems, without impacting the application at all.

The bottom of the OSI stack is all about essential network standards for system interconnection. everyone has to do these things the same way, or nothing will work. There is a binding responsibility on all manufacturers to play by these rules, in order to have products that they can sell.

OS vendors however are less keen on rigid rules and structures that prevent their platform from standing-out from the herd. The reason there has never been a fully OSI-compliant system is that no OS vendor wants to write one.

So, OSI layers 1-4 are solid, predictable, and essential. Layers 5 and 6 however are entirely optional. Applications will either write the code to make use of them, or they won't, depending on what they need.

Most modern applications just read data out of the Transport protocol segment. In those cases there are no encapsulated datagrams for L5/L6. the data in the segment payload is the applications data, so the application just attaches IO streams to the L4 port and reads/writes to/from it.

In the case of ICMP, since it doesn't use Layer4, the application just reads off the raw IP socket. Same concept.

[Layer 5](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Session_layer) is only used for applications that require network proxying or tunneling. The payload of this datagram is often another frame or packet that is being sent through a tunnel, or a segment being proxied through a SOCKS proxy. The application will usually either not know that a proxy is in play or will make use of the OS to handle layer 5 if it is applicable for that system, though some applications on some OSs may actually control the decapsulation of L5 datagrams. Often L5 operations are handled in the kernel with the use of a driver (VPN virtual network adapter, system proxy, etc).

Its notable that most layer 5 protocols are used to control interaction that has nothing to do with the applications desire to send/recieve messages, and is usually not meaningful to either system involved in the communication either. it is usually used to control the network so that those two systems CAN talk. In fact, most of the time the applications data stream is intercepted by the OS, and a system application handles the encapsulation of the outer datagram, so it takes the applications packets, and puts them in other packets that the application doesn't even know exist. The system application is in control of the data at that point.

[Layer 6](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Presentation_layer) is really not used. in any programming framework I've used, encoding is handled in the application, using the appropriate libraries. it is possible for applications to write in layer 6 operations if they want, using the OSs encoders/decoders or supply their own, but in my experience this is usually handled by the application and doesn't affect datagram encapsulation.

So, at the end of the day, all of this is for the purpose of giving an application IO streams it can read and write in order to send and receive messages over the network, with almost no foreknowledge of how the network works. That is 100% of what modern networking is about.

If a system uses a system wide proxy or a VPN, it will usually automatically encapsulate the L5 datagram, such that the sending application doesn't even know it is there. on the receiving end, the L5 header will have already been stripped out by the time it is received, because it has been processed by the proxy server or VPN endpoint, so the remote OS just pipes the the data out of the layer 4 payload to the application.

So a given packet will only have as many layers encapsulated in as it needs to have, to get the job done. There are low-level applications that operate only at layer 2, and don't contain L3+ components. there are internetwork layer applications that don't use L4+, so they don't encapsulate anything higher (like ICMP). You have to have all the layers below the one you wish to operate at, but you don't need any above it. Most common applications focus on reading and writing at layer 4, and let the OS worry about Layers 5 and 6 as needed.

Finally, I can understand why you are confused, and why its difficult to find good info on this topic. to really understand it all, you need some understanding of networking, application programming, and OS design, so its taken me many years to come to feel like I have a sufficient understanding of the way it all works.

Comment: Very helpful answer, thanks. If ICMP uses the application layer but not 6,5, or 4, could you explain the encapsulation process for this packet? I have no experience with this, couldn't find anything too helpful online so it's probably a really simple thing, thanks heaps.

Comment: so I expanded my answer quite a bit, but the gist of it comes down to the application layers ability to declare what layer it will operate at. all layers below that become mandatory. most applications in the real world read off TCP\UDP port data streams, so they are really only using layers 4 and down. if layer 5 is used, it is used by the OS rather than the application in most cases, so it is transparent to the app. really the whole goal to the network stack is to make it easy for apps to exchange mesages, so the app decides what protocols to use and and then just reads/writes the IO streams.

Comment: you may find value in this answer here: https://superuser.com/questions/984182/what-are-the-detailed-osi-model-steps-involved-in-connecting-to-a-website/984205#984205 it covers a bit of the coding-perspective on TCP/IP connections.

Comment: Brilliant info. Didn't really learn enough about this to draw conclusions about any of it previously, but this helped heaps. Thanks heaps for helping me understand this better

Answer (score 0):

ICMP is the [*Internet Control Message Protocol*](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc792). As the name implies, ICMP is an [*Internet Protocol*](https://wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_protocol_suite). It is *not* an [OSI](https://wikipedia.org/wiki/OSI_model) protocol.

The Internet Protocol stack only has four layers:

- Application
- Transport
- Internet
- [Link] (this layer is assumed to exist outside of the Internet, it is not specified by the Internet Protocol stack itself)

ICMP is an Internet layer protocol, which is layer 2 of the Internet Protocol stack.

There are other popular layered models for networking, for example the Ethernet stack:

- Link layer

  - Logical Link Control (LLC)
  - Media Access Control (MAC)

    - Reconciliation Sublayer (RS)
- PHY

  - Physical Coding Sublayer (PCS)
  - Physical Medium Attachment sublayer (PMA)
  - Physical Medium Dependent sublayer (PMD)

All of these 8 layers and sublayers together correspond to only one single layer in the Internet Protocol stack, the Link layer. And they correspond to two layers in the OSI Protocol stack, the Physical layer and the Data Link layer.

As you can see, all of these different stacks have different layers, and there is no guarantee that a protocol from one stack, for example IEEE 802.3cd from the Ethernet stack or ICMP from the Internet stack, can be perfectly mapped to a different stack.

For example, you cannot map ICMP to the Ethernet stack. You can *try* to map IEEE 802.3cd to the Internet stack, but that will be really imprecise: all you can say is that it belongs to the Link layer, but in the Ethernet stack, that layer is split into 8 layers and sublayers, and IEEE 802.3cd only belongs to one of those, not to all.

Likewise, if you try to map IEEE 802.3cd to the OSI stack, all you can say is that it belongs to the Physical layer, but in the Ethernet stack, that corresponds to three different sublayers, and IEEE 802.3cd only belongs to one of those.

Comment: Generally speaking, any protocol can be modeled conceptually using either the OSI or the DOD/DARPA stack, and usually neither stack gets it perfectly. for instance ICMP doesn't use a Transport layer protocol.