# What useful work a netbios on an ethernet do

Tags: netbios

This is more about basic understanding NetBIOS. I read NetBIOSis an API and if I understand correctly NetBIOS can be used directly on an Ethernet network without TCP/IP or NetBEUI.
What useful function ( if any) such a configuration accomplish.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

well, you have to consider when [NetBIOS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NetBIOS) was groundbreaking. Back when Microsoft Implemented NetBIOS in 1985 for MS-DOS, IP wasn't entirely dominant in business networks. Even into the late-nineties, alternate network and inter-network layers like  Novell IPX/SPX and IBM SNA (and a large number of other protocols) where competing in that space, so [NetBIOS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NetBIOS) was implemented as  a Session Layer protocol which could use many different network, inter-network, and transport protocol combinations. Early versions of NetBIOS were designed to work with non-ethernet networks like IBMs [Token Ring](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Token_Ring) protocols.

NetBIOS addressed LAN protocols using [NetBIOS Frames](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NetBIOS_Frames), but in order to use Internetwork protocols, NetBIOS needed a special sever called a WINS server to resolve NetBIOS names on other, connected LANs.

Now-a-days NetBIOS runs over TCP/IP ([NBT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NetBIOS_over_TCP/IP)), and no longer needs concern itself with many other lower layer protocols, but that is the result of continual evolution over the course of decades.

Comment: Am I correct in saying classic  NETBIOS is  an API  and not a protocol whereas  NetBIOS Frames is a protocol ?

Comment: Yes, NBF is a Transport layer protocol. And technically, since NetBIOS classic operates at the Session Layer, it is a protocol as well. don't fixate so much on the "API" bit though. All  protocols above layer 2 exist as APIs. check out this answer on how the application layer drives connectivity by operating the Berkeley Sockets API: https://superuser.com/a/984205/171793