# A switch is usually a layer 2 device and modem is layer 1 device, but the router, which is between both of them, is layer 3

Tags: networking, router, switch

It seems a bit weird to me that the device that is between the devices for layer 1 and layer 2 is the device for a layer that is not in between in the whole communication process.

Is there something that I am not understanding or is it actually like that?

Comment: Do you have an actual question?

Comment: A cable modem is only layer1 on one of its sides (the side connecting to the service provider). the part of it that connects to your router is layer2. thats why a router is not strictly required. you can just jack a standard PC NIC into a cable modem with an RJ45 and the two devices will speak in ethernet/802.3 or whatever applicable L2 protocol. everyone having thier own Internet Access router wasn't common until about 2004, when households started having more than one device connected. before that most people connected their 1 PC directly to the modem

Comment: So i think you are confusing modern cable/dsl/fiber modems for old POTS modems that were installed into a PC (or directly connected to it via a serial port). since those old devices were directly connected to the PC, there was no need to translate the signal into data using a network protocol, and analog-to-digital signal processing was pretty much all the device did. when you separate a modem from a PC by using a network cable however, this was no longer possible, so modern modems ceased to be strictly L1 devices.

Comment: Lots of other devices fail to fall strictly into OSI layers. for instance I have Smart switches that for the most part only support layer2 functions, but have a management interface I can access via IP. that doesn't make the switch a L3 switch, since the switching features it provides all operate at layer 2, but the device is still clearly capable of being assigned an IP address, and binding a web application to a TCP port for me to access.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I do detect one more potential for misunderstanding. just because a device is a layer 2 device, and operates by processing frames, doesn't mean that those frames don't contain L3 packets. The whole L1 -> L3 -> L2 thing indicates you may be thinking about it wrong. the devices are deployed where they are because there is a critical function that must be performed in that niche; it just happens that the critical function a modem is designed to provide is physical signal processing, and the function that the router performs is internetwork communication, which requires processing at L3.

Comment: @FrankThomas your smart switch is theoretically also acting on layer 1, as your finger communicates with it on the physical layer ;) Anyways, good explanation of the OSI model in the real world! Maybe you want to consolidate the comments into an answer?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so the first thing you need to understand is that the OSI model is a very useful conceptual framework for separating and explaining the relationship between the many concerns that must be addressed for modern networking to exist. That said however, no OS actually conforms perfectly to it.

Next, consider that a router is said to be a Layer 3 device, because it performs its primary function using layers 1->3. While some layers of the OSI model are optional and even seldom used (5 and 6 come to mind), they are all above layer 3. With the exception of the Application Layer (L7), a device that functions at a given layer MUST implement all the layers below it.

One seriously overlooked consideration for understanding the OSI model is that the Application Layer is Much more important than most network jockeys understand. see my answer here on how programs use the upper layers of the stack to achieve common tasks: [What are the detailed OSI model steps involved in connecting to a website?](https://superuser.com/questions/984182/what-are-the-detailed-osi-model-steps-involved-in-connecting-to-a-website/984205#984205)

You can divide up the OSI model into upper and lower layers. layers 1-2 are implemented almost entirely in hardware, firmware, and low level drivers. layer 3 can be done entirely in software, though most routers use specialized hardware to process layer 3 traffic, just to speed things up and increase capacity while reducing reliance on shared resources like RAM and CPU. Layers 4 and above however are entirely software. Modern applications generally care about layers 4 and up, and when they do care about layer 3, it is only to the extent that they need traffic to get to layer 4 so they have to tell the OS what interface to use.

One of the things that really messes people up when learning the OSI, is that the characterization of where a given real world device fits into the model sometimes doesn't quite match.

The OSI Model defines a set of related concerns and describes the functions that must occur in each layer, and names devices that fill those functions. For instance to the OSI a "router" is a layer 3 (layer 1->3) device that performs the functions required for enabling internetwork communication. that said a most real world routers implement technologies like Firewalling and NAT (layer 4), VPNs and proxies (layer 5), application gateways like application firewalls or DNS Masquerading (layer 7).
In this case the router is still a layer 3 device because the primary function that a router plays is internetwork communication.

Next it seems like you expect the devices that make up a network to be in some kind of progressive order, based on what they are connected to. This is not really correct. It is not at all weird that a Modem is layer 1, and connects to a layer 3 router, which itself connects to a layer 2 switch. the router connects multiple networks that are themselves composed of layer 2 network (as opposed to internetwork)
devices. Thats kind of the point. networks are made of L2 devices, Internetworks are made of networks connected together by layer3 devices.

So imagine that you had connected a modem to a switch then to your router (layers 1 -> 2 -> 3) as you appear to assert. what you have done is connected a switch to expand your ISPs network, not your own. you probably want to extend your own network with the switch, so because you want to have your own network and connect it to your ISPs net, you need to drop a router in between their network and yours. so you end up with L1 -> L3 -> L2.

Finally, when you are considering the OSI model, I encourage you to ignore the existence of a so-called "Brouter" aka a "Layer 3 switch". they exist, and are in fact quite common but just consider them L2 switches with advanced features (like the firewall NAT/PAT router described above). Like I said, the OSI model is conceptual, and has little to do with the kinds of devices that people want to buy to support their needs.

so to sum up:

- OSI is a conceptual model that defines functions a given device must have to provide a key technical capability and its prerequisites.
- Just because a device has a feature that relies on an layer above its "operational layer" doesn't automatically mean that its a higher layer device. look for the primary function that type of device plays in the grand scheme of things. don't be distracted by auxiliary features/capabilities.
- A device that operates at layer 4 must implement layers 1-3 as well.
- The application layer drives everything.

Hope that helps. I had similar questions 20 years ago. keep at it, and it will eventually gel.